# funny format when copy from CSV

Tags: excel, csv

I used python to write some text to csv but it is stored in funny format.
output data is saved here:[example data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kx55w5ws7zrjx7j/test.csv?dl=0)
for example, it is read as the below in csv excel

[text shown in CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpdAV.jpg)
[image]

when i copy it to other platforms(notepad, word, web application) it turns into something else
[after copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eUTa.jpg)
[image]

I tried a numerous method include formatting with the CSV but it just wont work.
Could someone please help me.

With thanks,
Iverson

Comment: Please post raw input data, your code and desired output, we're not here to speculate on something we can't reproduce

Comment: thanks mate, i don't have the code anymore and won't be able to reproduce it as the site is down.
Sample of the file can be found here:https://www.dropbox.com/s/kx55w5ws7zrjx7j/test.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what you mean...

Your file has `TAB`s between many characters. But every line starts and ends in a double quote (`"`). So the whole line is **one** value (cell).

Comment: hey Michel, thanks for the reply. Perhaps I haven't articulate it very well. If you could look at the test file you will know what I mean dropbox.com/s/kx55w5ws7zrjx7j/test.csv?dl=0
at the moment that column  isn't usable because as you describe there are many tabs between characters and also there are double quotes.....I wonder why it wasn't displaying its real value in excel CSV and only show the real value when copy the cell value to another platform(e.g. notepad).What is the best way to "clean" this data?

Comment: Euh, remove all `TAB`s? Open in Notepad, copy a tab, paste into replace dialog, replace all... Better: find out where the `TAB`s come from!